# Fill the Diagonal of Each Matrix in a 3D numpy Array with a Vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, diagonal

Having a 3D numpy array, where each 2D slice represents an individual matrix. I'm looking to replace the diagonal elements of every matrix with a specific set of values.

For instance, if I have a `3x3x3` array:

```
array([[[a1, a2, a3],
        [a4, a5, a6],
        [a7, a8, a9]],

       [[b1, b2, b3],
        [b4, b5, b6],
        [b7, b8, b9]],

       [[c1, c2, c3],
        [c4, c5, c6],
        [c7, c8, c9]]])
```

I'd like to replace the diagonals `[a1, a5, a9]`, `[b1, b5, b9]`, and `[c1, c5, c9]` with a new set of values for each matrix. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use integer indexing:

```
import numpy as np

# Setup:
arr = np.zeros((3, 4, 6), dtype=int)
vectors = np.random.randint(1, 9, size=(3, 4))

# Should work for arbitrary `arr` with ndim >= 2
n = min(arr.shape[-2:])
idx = np.arange(n)

# Note that `vectors.shape` must broadcast with
# `(*arr.shape[:-2], n)` for this to work:

arr[..., idx, idx] = vectors
```

Comment: Neat solution! I guess it should be faster than `np.eye` masking.

Comment: It seems that it's cleaner to use `np.diag_indices` or `np.diag_indices_from`

Comment: I considered using `diag_indices`, but ended up needing to unpack the tuple it returns to combine it with the `...` indexer for the preceding dimensions. So it was easier to just use `arange`. This is also how `diag_indices` is implemented under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `np.eye` masking.

```
zeros = np.zeros((3,4,6))
vectors = np.random.randint(1 , 9, (3, 4)) # Generating random 3x4 integer array between 1 and 9

mask = np.eye(zeros.shape[1], zeros.shape[2], dtype=bool)
zeros[:, mask] = vectors
```

Here is the output of `print(zeros)`.

```
[[[2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 4. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 7. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 4. 0. 0.]]

 [[7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 4. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 6. 0. 0.]]

 [[3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 3. 0. 0.]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can craft the indices for direct indexing:

```
# example input
a = np.zeros((3,3,3), dtype=int)

N = min(a.shape)
idx1 = np.repeat(range(N), N)
idx2 = np.tile(range(N), N)

a[idx1, idx2, idx2] = np.arange(1, 10)
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3]],

       [[4, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 0],
        [0, 0, 6]],

       [[7, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 9]]])
```

Intermediates:

```
# idx1
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

# idx2
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future, when numpy implements the functionality described below, this will be a one-liner. Until then, you'll need to use an indexing or masking method shown in one of the other answers.

---

The documentation for [`numpy.diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) (as of v1.25) says:

> Starting in NumPy 1.9 it returns a read-only view on the original array. Attempting to write to the resulting array will produce an error.
>
> In some future release, it will return a read/write view and writing to the returned array will alter your original array. The returned array will have the same type as the input array.

In some future release of numpy, you should be able to write to the view returned by `np.diagonal` directly.

```
np.diagonal(zeros, axis1=-2, axis2=-1) = vectors
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]],

                [[10, 11, 12],
                 [13, 14, 15],
                 [16, 17, 18]],

                [[19, 20, 21],
                 [22, 23, 24],
                 [25, 26, 27]]])

new_values = [[-1, -2, -3], [-4, -5, -6], [-7, -8, -9]]

# Correct vectorized diagonal replacement:
# Create a 2D index array
diagonal_indices = np.arange(arr.shape[1])  
print(diagonal_indices)#[0 1 2]
# Use advanced indexing
arr[:, diagonal_indices, diagonal_indices] = new_values  

print(arr)
"""[[[-1  2  3]
  [ 4 -2  6]
  [ 7  8 -3]]

 [[-4 11 12]
  [13 -5 15]
  [16 17 -6]]

 [[-7 20 21]
  [22 -8 24]
  [25 26 -9]]]
"""
```

Method 2 :

```
diagonal_indices = np.diag_indices(arr.shape[1])
arr[:, diagonal_indices[0], diagonal_indices[1]] = np.expand_dims(new_values, axis=0)

print(arr)
[[[-1  2  3]
  [ 4 -2  6]
  [ 7  8 -3]]

 [[-4 11 12]
  [13 -5 15]
  [16 17 -6]]

 [[-7 20 21]
  [22 -8 24]
  [25 26 -9]]]
```